# Finding $E(X^r\mid Y)$ of an exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $(X,Y)$ denote a two-dimensional random vector with an absolutely continuous distribution with density function

$$p(x,y) = \frac{1}{y}\exp(-y), \qquad 0 < x < y < \infty.$$

Find $E(X^r\mid Y)$ for $r = 1,2,\ldots$

My solution:

$$p_y(y) = \exp(-y)$$

$$p_{x\mid y}(x\mid y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p_y(y)} = \frac{1}{y}$$

$$E(X\mid Y) = \int_0^y x p_{x\mid y}(x\mid y) \, dx = \frac{y^3}{2}$$

Not sure if I came out with the correct results, and not sure how to find the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

You've found the marginal and conditional distributions correctly. As for the general rule, keep in mind that $$\Bbb E(X^r\mid Y=y)=\int_0^y\frac{x^r}{y}\,dx=\frac1y\int_0^yx^r\,dx.$$ Since an antiderivative of $x^r$ is $\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ for any integer $r\ne-1,$ then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$\int_0^yx^r\,dx=\left[\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\right]_{x=0}^{x=y}=\frac{y^{r+1}}{r+1}-\frac{0^{r+1}}{r+1}=\frac{y^{r+1}}{r+1}$$ for any non-negative integer $r$ and any positive real $y$. Thus, $$\Bbb E(X^r\mid Y=y)=\frac1y\cdot\frac{y^{r+1}}{r+1}=\frac{y^r}{r+1}.$$

Comment: Is the antiderivative just simply $\frac{x^{r+n}}{r+n}$ for each n=0,1,2,...n?

Comment: Not quite. $\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ would be an antiderivative of $x^r$ for $r=1,2,3,....$ Given that, can you evaluate the definite integral?

Comment: The number goes to infinity, so I'm not sure if we can solve the definite integral. If we can find the definite integral, is it $\frac{y^{r+n-1}}{r+n}$-$\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: What number is going to infinity? The number $y$ is an arbitrary positive real, but fixed. The number $r$ is an arbitrary positive integer, but fixed. Since $\dfrac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ is an antiderivative of $x^r,$ then what does the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tell us that $$\int_0^y x^r\,dx$$ is? We'll get an expression dependent on $y$ and $r$ only--there should be no $n,$ $x,$ or any other variable. All that's left to do at that point is multiply by $\frac1y$, and we're done.